# Vercel disable auto-refresh website on new deployment

Tags: next.js, vercel

I have a next.js website hosted on Vercel where people input longer text into textboxes. Every time I deploy a new version, all clients' websites refresh and they lose their data.
There must be a way of disabling this auto-refresh.

Steps to Reproduce

1. Create a website with text-input and enter some text (optional)
2. Deploy a new version and wait for it to finish building
3. Defocus the browser or the tab
4. Refocus the tab and it will refresh, loosing all changes.